# Error building release flavor for Android application

Tags: android, build.gradle

I'm studying the basics of build types and trying to create release and debug flavors for my app. Firstly, I've created a directory config in the root folder of my app. Then I generated a signed APK key and set the path as config directory. Then I made the following changes in build.gradle. The following is my build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sarthak.chitchatmessagingapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

signingConfigs {
    chitchatReleaseConfig {
        storeFile file("../config/releaseapkkey.jks");
        storePassword("123456");
        keyAlias("releaseapkkey");
        keyPassword("123456");
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    } release {
        minifyEnabled true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.chitchatReleaseConfig
    } releaseDebug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        zipAlignEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.chitchatReleaseConfig
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

However, I keep getting the following error.

```
Error:(25, 0) Could not find method release() for arguments [build_ehqm3plmr2s7xq0x3e59oqqgt$_run_closure1$_closure5$_closure8@7595456a] on BuildType_Decorated{name=debug, debuggable=true, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=SigningConfig_Decorated{name=debug, storeFile=C:\Users\Sarthak\.android\debug.keystore, storePassword=android, keyAlias=AndroidDebugKey, keyPassword=android, storeType=C:\Users\Sarthak\.android\debug.keystore, v1SigningEnabled=true, v2SigningEnabled=true}, embedMicroApp=false, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[C:\Users\Sarthak\Documents\AndroidProjects\ChitChat Messaging App\build\intermediates\proguard-files\proguard-android.txt-2.3.2, C:\Users\Sarthak\Documents\AndroidProjects\ChitChat Messaging App\app\proguard-rules.pro], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.
```

Can somebody help me figure out what the error is all about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a newline before each buildType:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...
    } 
    release {
        ...
    } 
    releaseDebug {
       ...
    }
}
```

That is, do not put the new buildType on the same line as the closing bracket of the previous buildType like this `} release {`

I was able to trigger your problem in my project by using your style.  I was able to fix it by putting in the newline as I suggested.  This must have something to do with the way Gradle does its parsing.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked. Android Studio is weird sometimes. :P